# communicate with arduino over serial

Tags: serial, arduino

I have a raspberry pi b+ running raspbian jessie, and I want to use the command line to send strings to the arduino,  I don't need to receive anything though. I have found a couple of ways of doing this, but there are no files in /dev/ called ttyS. I have used the arduino with the official serial monitor that comes with the ide, and it works perfectly. I have tried `echo "Hello World!" >/dev/ttyAMA0` but it says `permission denied`

I am loged in as pi over ssh, as suggested in deacs answer, I did `sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi` and it's not saying permission denied, but nothing is being recieved by the arduino. it is the only thing plugged into usb.

The output of `groups` is:

```
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please not that you can always edit your original question to provide additional information as requested in comments (to the question or to answers). This way all readers will easily catch all relevant information without parsing through multiple comments. Thanks.

Comment: ... and sorry about the mistake in my edit (looks I am blind this morning). Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Johns answer sudjested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253344/opening-serial-connection-to-arduino-through-bash), I used the command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb
```

then opened `/dev/ttyUSB0` with by doing

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a few things before being able to use `/dev/ttyAMA0`

1. Add your user (that will use `ttyAMA0`) to the `dialout` group:

   - `sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi` (`pi` is the user here)
2. Disable linux using the serial port as a terminal:

   - `sudo raspi-config`
   - Select `Interfacing Options`
   - Select `Serial`
   - "Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?" Select `<No>`
   - "The serial interface is disabled" `<Ok>`
   - Select `<Finish>` and select `<Yes>` when asked "Would you like to reboot now"
3. After reboot, edit the /boot/config.txt file to enable uart on boot:

   - `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`
   - change `enable_uart = 0` to `enable_uart = 1`
   - save file and reboot again `sudo reboot`

After reboot you should be able to send commands over `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

Answer (score 1):

The UART connected to GPIO 14/15 (pins 8/10) is normally named `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

Only the Pi3 defaults to using `/dev/ttyS0` as a different UART is connected.

So to talk to the Arduino try

```
echo "Hello World!" >/dev/ttyAMA0
```

Comment: it says permission denied

Comment: sorry, i'm not very good with chmod

Answer (score 0):

On all recent Raspbian The default serial is `/dev/serial0`. This is actually a link to the actual device, which can vary.

Comment: yours works too, but it still still says permission denied. @Milliways

Comment: What user are you logged in as? What does `groups` show?

Comment: Do NOT post extra detail into Comments, put in your answer. There is no need to use @ when responding. Based on your response `pi` is a member of `dialout` which should be the group of the serial port, so it should work, but as you have not specified exactly what you have tried no one can be sure.